# How insert if a row not already exists ? (query)

Tags: sql, mariadb

*My tables :*

```
FirstTable
--------------------
'id' INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
'label' VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
'secondTable_id' INT(11) UNIQUE NOT NULL


SecondTable
--------------------
'id' INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
'label' VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
```

*Wrong migration script :*

```js
IF ('Str Test' NOT IN (SELECT label from FirstTable)) THEN 
    INSERT INTO FirstTable
    (label, secondTable_Id) VALUES 
    ('Str Test', (SELECT id FROM SecondTable WHERE label = 'Str Match'));
END IF;
```

I try insert new row if `FirstTable.label == Str Test` isn't already exists but i get an error :

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

---

Update : I know IF/ELSE can only use in procedure/function but I hope we can do something like. Any help will be much appreciate ❤️

---

'Paul T.' Answer :
If values can throws SQL errors at insertion (like unique or foreign keys), you can use `INSERT IGNORE` like bellow.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO FirstTable
    (label, SecondTable_id) VALUES 
    ('Str Test', (SELECT id FROM SecondTable WHERE label = 'Str Match'));
```

Comment: What is the table structure for FirstTable? ... is either one of the two insert values primary or unique? ... is this query some part of a stored procedure, function, or trigger? If so, may need more context.

Comment: This script need to be a Query, that why I update my post. 
FirstTable got only 3 properties (id, label, secondTable_id). secondTable_id is unique key of SecondTable and label are unique too.

Comment: Now knowing that the FirstTable's `label` and `secondTable_id` are unique (if I understood correctly), then you can simply add `IGNORE` with the INSERT, which will only generate warnings without causing errors when duplicates are encountered: `INSERT IGNORE INTO FirstTable ...`, no `IF` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks ! In order to deepen my knowledge, what can I do if `label` was not unique ?

Comment: That seems like an odd migration, because it looks like the second table is already a lookup table, where the id from there could simply be used as a foreign key anywhere else? ... which seems to make the need for the FirstTable pointless. Is the migration simply trying to copy all the second table values to the first, or are there other inserts?

Comment: Actually this does not represent my tables as a whole.
I need to verify that a non-unique column value is already stored before inserting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO FirstTable(label, secondTable_Id)
SELECT 'Str Test', id 
FROM SecondTable 
WHERE label = 'Str Match' and not exists(
                            select * 
                            from FirstTable 
                            where label = 'Str Test')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways to insert only when it doesn't exist already in the target table.

The first is procedural, with an insert from select.

```
SET @FirstLabel = 'Str Test';
SET @SecondLabel = 'Str Match';
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from FirstTable WHERE label = @FirstLabel) 
THEN 
    INSERT INTO FirstTable (label, secondTable_Id) 
    SELECT @FirstLabel, id 
    FROM SecondTable 
    WHERE label = @SecondLabel
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
END IF;
```

The second is an insert from a select with a `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SET @FirstLabel = 'Str Test';
SET @SecondLabel = 'Str Match';
INSERT INTO FirstTable (secondTable_Id, label) 
SELECT t2.id, @FirstLabel
FROM SecondTable t2
WHERE t2.label = @SecondLabel
  AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM FirstTable t1
     WHERE t1.secondTable_Id = t2.id
       AND t1.label = @FirstLabel
  )
ORDER BY t2.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=98535024e39998540d6e016f29387c6f)*